# Is it possible to "copy" a function into another process and execute it in a thread without using LoadLibrary?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I'm trying to write and execute a single function function:

```
int thread(void) {
    WCHAR boxTitle = L"testing...";
    WCHAR message = L"hello?";
    int (*MessageBoxW)(HWND, LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR, UINT);
    MessageBoxW = (LPVOID)0x7FFCA28E2750; // address of MessageBoxW function in user32.dll on my machine
    MessageBoxW(NULL, message, boxTitle, MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

In another process using `VirtualAllocEx`, `WriteProcessMemory`, and `CreateRemoteThread`:

```
int main(void) {

    HANDLE hProc;
    LPVOID baseAddr;
    int funcSize;

    funcSize = (int)main - (int)thread;
    hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, 10724); // notepad.exe PID on my machine
    baseAddr = VirtualAllocEx(hProc, NULL, funcSize, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

    WriteProcessMemory(hProc, baseAddr, &thread, funcSize, NULL);
    CreateRemoteThread(hProc, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)baseAddr, NULL, 0, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hProc);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the message box doesn't properly display the `LPCWSTR` arguments that I provide to the MessageBoxW function through my function pointer. The message box appears, but the box title and message body are blank.

Here is a link to an image displaying this issue:

[image: output of MessageBoxW function]

I have a feeling that this issue involves something with character encoding and the way that I have copied my function into the virtual address space of the remote process, but I really can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: *message, boxTitle* point to what in context of another process ?

Comment: you can simply copy only function which have no imports and relocs, not use pointers to some data

Comment: @RbMm unless your function is a lightweight leaf function (uses no stack, no nonvolatile registers, calls no other functions), you also need to inform the kernel of your function's structure for unwinding purposes. You may also have to register the function as a valid call target to pass cfg. Injecting code on x64 is more complicated than just copying code.

Comment: @RaymondChen - you mistake. not need register function as a valid call target to pass cfg - if we allocate executable memory - all it is valid call target. and we not need have structure for unwinding if we not use it. and if need handle exception we can register *VEH* (after call `RtlSetProtectedPolicy`). really i can inject raw function and then if need load dll even to process where all current mitigation on - CFG(with export suppression, StrictMode), ACG, etc. your comment upvoted only because people trust you. but very few have knowledge in this area

Comment: even Code Integrity Guard (CIG) not problem if shell code want load not signed dll (from disk) and have support from injector process. low integrity, app container too.so all is possible, another question - it is really not trivial

Comment: *unless your function is a lightweight...need to inform the kernel of your function's structure* -  mistake ! need do this only if we want use *__try/__except* (direct or indirect via *try/catch*), but no any problem not use *__try/__except*. use(register) *VEH* we can even inside shellcode. *register the function as a valid call target to pass cfg.* - not need, all memory range allocated by VirtualAllocEx - is valid cfg tagget by default

Comment: @RbMm I wasn't sure about CFG, which is why I said "may". Registering unwind codes is definitely needed if an exception occurs. Otherwise, unwinding will not take place properly. Now, whether this is "necessary" depends on whether you are looking from the point of view of "I want to do this in the architecturally correct and supported way" (e.g., you are writing production code), or from the point of view "I am malware that wants to get code to execute and I don't care if the process becomes irretrievably corrupted after I get injected, because that's not my problem"

Comment: @RaymondChen not agree with *Registering unwind codes is definitely needed* - not need. what is mean *exception occurs* ?! it can not suddenly occur at random place. if we not do errors in code and special raise exception, not call winapi which do this on fail(almost not exist) - will be not need exception handler. and how i say we can register *VEH*. and absolute not agree why you decide that code will be not correct, not "production level" etc ? about CFG - all call targets in allocated virtual memory (unlike mapped section) is valid by default

Comment: Exceptions can occur at random places without you calling out to any Windows APIs. For example, stack guard exceptions, in-page errors. They are very unlikely, but failure to register unwind codes is technically a violation of the ABI. It may work in practice, but it is not following the rules.

Comment: @RaymondChen: I beg to differ about inpage errors. If you get an inpage error on the stack you can't recover. If you can get an inpage error on the virtual memory slab containing injected code, you can get an inpage error on the data memory containing the unwind information. Note this particular method does not result in the code being mapped from the disk in the end but in an anonymous page, so it won't care if the disk the executable is running on goes away.

Comment: But I think it's actually simpler than that. If unwinding off ThreadProc is a fatal error, than not finding unwind data for ThreadProc is merely a fatal error a little sooner.

Comment: @Joshua A program that is CD-based could install a vectored handler to handle inpage errors by asking the user to put the CD back in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't calculate the size of a function the way you are. There is no guarantee that `main` and `thread` will be stored sequentially in memory, or that `main` will be stored after `thread`.

You are also not copying the actual characters of the string literals into the remote process, you are only copying the *pointers* to the string literals. You can't share pointers across process boundaries, each process has a different *virtual address space*, and a pointer within a given process' address space is only valid within that process.  You need to allocate additional memory in the remote process to copy the characters into, and then make the remote thread pass pointers to that memory to `MessageBoxW()`.

Not to mention, you are not performing any cleanup at all, so you are leaking memory and system resources that are allocated in the remote process, letting them just sit unused once the remote thread is finished running.

You will have to do something more like the following (this is for x86 only, it gets a bit more complicated for x64. Forgive me if I get the opcodes wrong a little, my x86 is a bit rusty):

```cpp
static const WCHAR *boxTitle = L"testing...";
static const WCHAR *message = L"hello?";

#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct myThreadOpCodes
{
    BYTE push_uType;
    DWORD uType;
    BYTE push_lpCaption;
    DWORD lpCaption;
    BYTE push_lpText;
    DWORD lpText;
    BYTE push_hWnd;
    DWORD hWnd;
    BYTE call_MessageBoxW;
    LONG offset_MessageBoxW;
    BYTE xor_EAX[2];
    BYTE ret;
    WORD numBytes;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

int main(void)
{
    HANDLE hProc, hThread;
    LPVOID baseAddr;
    myThreadOpCodes code;

    hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, 10724);
    if (!hProc)
        return 0;

    // TODO: if ASLR is enabled, to get the real address of MessageBoxW within the 
    // target process, you will have to first enumerate the loaded modules in the
    // process looking for the actual base address of kernel32.dll (see
    // http://bytepointer.com/articles/locating_kernel32_in_aslr_memory.htm)
    // then enumerate its exports table looking for the real address of
    // MessageBoxW...
    void *lpMessageBox = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32")), "MessageBoxW");

    code.push_uType = 0x68;
    code.uType = MB_OK;
    code.push_lpCaption = 0x68;
    code.lpCaption = 0;
    code.push_lpText = 0x68;
    code.lpText = 0;
    code.push_hWnd = 0x68;
    code.hWnd = 0;
    code.call_MessageBoxW = 0xE8;
    code.offset_MessageBoxW = 0;
    code.xor_EAX[0] = 0x33;
    code.xor_EAX[1] = 0xC0;
    code.ret = 0xCA;
    code.numBytes = sizeof(LPVOID);

    int TitleLen = (lstrlenW(lpTitle) + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR);
    int TextLen = (lstrlenW(message) + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR);

    baseAddr = VirtualAllocEx(hProc, NULL, sizeof(code) + TitleLen + TextLen, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (baseAddr)
    {
        code.lpCaption = DWORD_PTR(baseAddr) + sizeof(code);
        code.lpText = code.lpCaption + TitleLen;
        code.offset_MessageBoxW = LONG_PTR(lpMessageBox) - (LONG_PTR(baseAddr) + offsetof(myThreadOpCodes, xor_EAX));

        if (WriteProcessMemory(hProc, baseAddr, &code, sizeof(code) + TitleLen + TextLen, NULL))
        {
            DWORD oldProtection;
            if (VirtualProtectEx(hProc, baseAddr, sizeof(code), PAGE_EXECUTE, &oldProtection))
            {
                FlushInstructionCache(hProc, baseAddr, sizeof(code));

                hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProc, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)baseAddr, NULL, 0, NULL);
                if (hThread)
                {
                    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
                    CloseHandle(hThread);
                }
            }
        }

        VirtualFreeEx(hProc, baseAddr, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    }

    CloseHandle(hProc);

    return 0;
}
```

That being said, a much simpler way to inject a whole function into another process is to implement the function in a DLL so you can write code for the function normally, and then inject a simple call to `LoadLibrary()` into the target process to load the DLL, and then the DLL can call the function as needed.  But you seem to want to avoid this route, since your question is about avoiding `LoadLibrary()`.

Comment: Having actually had to do this, I found it far simpler to write the thing out longhand in assembly and inject it. My code doesn't look like yours because I use an actual .asm file but it's the same idea.

Comment: Same idea.  However you can encode the raw ASM bytes into a memory buffer, and then copy that buffer to the remote process. But what is important for this discussion is the use of pointers within that ASM code for the string parameters to `MessageBoxW`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and explanation. You have made some good points and I'll definitely attempt to implement these changes now that I understand them.

Comment: instead encode the raw ASM bytes (which is very not comfortable) better write shell code in asm file. for  calculate the size of a function, better place it in separate code section, and use *$* in sections name for set section order. also about *ASLR* - kernel try load dll at the same address in all processes. it is random but the same, if only memory for dll not already occupied. in latest windows kernel load dlls in special memory range, where virtual memory not allocated when starting address set to 0. so very low possibility that user32 will be not at place. and this not related to ASLR

Answer (score 0):

With this approach, no assembly is necessary, but you have to be careful to add all necessary functions, strings, etc. to the data structure.

(I didn't add any error checks and cleanup.)

```
#include <windows.h>

#ifndef __MINGW32__
#define CODE_SEG(seg) __declspec(code_seg(seg))
#else
#define CODE_SEG(seg) __attribute__((section(seg)))
#endif

typedef int WINAPI func_MessageBoxW(HWND, LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR, UINT);

struct data
{
  func_MessageBoxW *fMessageBoxW;
  wchar_t boxTitle[11];
  wchar_t message[7];
};

static CODE_SEG(".text$1") DWORD WINAPI inj(LPVOID para)
{
  struct data *data = para;
  data->fMessageBoxW(NULL, data->message, data->boxTitle, MB_OK);
  return 0;
}

CODE_SEG(".text$2") int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  HANDLE hProc;
  LPVOID baseAddr;
  size_t funcSize, fullSize;
  int pid;
  struct data data;
  HMODULE user32;

  if (argc < 2)
    return 1;

  user32 = LoadLibrary("user32.dll");
  data.fMessageBoxW = (func_MessageBoxW*)GetProcAddress(user32, "MessageBoxW");
  wcscpy(data.boxTitle, L"testing...");
  wcscpy(data.message, L"hello?");

  pid = atoi(argv[1]);
  funcSize = (size_t)&main - (size_t)&inj;
  fullSize = funcSize + sizeof(data);
  hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);
  baseAddr = VirtualAllocEx(hProc, NULL, fullSize, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

  WriteProcessMemory(hProc, baseAddr, &data, sizeof(data), NULL);
  WriteProcessMemory(hProc, (void*)((size_t)baseAddr + sizeof(data)), &inj, funcSize, NULL);
  CreateRemoteThread(hProc, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)((size_t)baseAddr + sizeof(data)), baseAddr, 0, NULL);
  CloseHandle(hProc);

  return 0;
}
```